# Upload files from client to server and vice versa in python

Tags: python

Started to implement this project in C++, however I figured Python would be a better choice going forward for x-platform.

Goal here is to create a simple file server and then create a client.  Client should be able to upload files to the server and download files from the server.

My code for the client is:

```
import socket

def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port =  5000

        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((host,port))

        choice = raw_input("Upload or Download? (u/d):")
        if choice == 'd':
            filename = raw_input("File to Download? (q to quit): ")
            if filename != 'q':
                s.send(filename)
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if data[:6] == "EXISTS":
                    filesize = long(data[6:])
                    message = raw_input("File found on the server!," +str(filesize)+"bytes, continue with download? y/n:")
                if message == "y":
                    s.send('OK')
                    f = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv = len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    while totalRecv < filesize:
                        data = s.recv(1024)
                        totalRecv += len(data)
                        f.write(data)
                        print ("Percentage Completed: "+"{0:.2f}".format((totalRecv/float(filesize))*100))
                    print ("File has been Downloaded!")
            else:
                print ("File doesnt exist!")
        else:
            filename = raw_input("File to Upload? (q to quit): ")
        #    if filename != 'q':

            print ("Upload Function Coming Soon")
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The code for the server is:

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        sock.send("EXISTS" + str(os.path.getsize(filename)))
        userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        sock.send("ERR")

    sock.close()

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(5)

    print ("Server Started")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ("Client Connected:") + str(addr) + ">"
        t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("retrThread", c))
        t.start()

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

I have it just fine for the download of the file, and thinking about it, I should be able to just reverse process for the upload portion of the client (instead of fetch the download, I basically copy the server part to perform the upload)...however I just cant seem to wrap my head around how to do so.  I'm not worried at this point over the hard coded port etc---will fix that later, however does anyone have any suggestions going forward with this?

I need to emphasize that I am using python < v3 (I know--its old) however its a program limitation that I need to adhere to (hence the raw_input() v. input())